# Set nunit to build before test, without project building when solution is built

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

It the solution properties we have set the test project not to build. This is because not all developers have nunit installed, and expecting them to install it just to build the project will cause resentment toward nunit.

This has also resulted in it being much harder to run the tests, we have to build the run tests.

Is there a way to exclude the project so there are no references to / dependencies on nunit libraries, and when a programmer asks to run unit tests, they (the tests) are built?

(using: visual studio 2012 professional)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding the NUnit libraries and adapter as NuGet packages ?
Doing that would make the build run and working - doing the necessary download without bothering the developer, that is NOTHING to install at all.

You could choose between adding the nuget packages to the solution/source control, or let it download on demand. 
For some details, I have a blogpost on this approach http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/11/part-3-unit-testing-with-traits-and-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2012-using-the-tfs-build-and-the-new-nuget-adapter-approach.aspx

Note that the nuget approach doesn't require TFS, it works nicely with just VS.